# Yii upload file from cjuidialog

Tags: ajax, file-upload, yii

Why I can't upload files from cjuidialog in Yii?

```
<div class="form">
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'edit-user-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
        'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
            'validateOnChange' => true,
        )
    ));
    ?>
    <fieldset>

            <?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($model)); ?>

            <div>
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'rubric_image'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'rubric_image'); ?>
            </div>

        <div>
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Upload'); ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

On standart html page, the file is sent, but if using cjuidialog, file not sent. In what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This [yii wiki arrticle](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/72/cjuidialog-and-ajaxsubmitbutton/) explains very detailed how to display a form on a CJuiDialog.
I dont think the problem is the fileupload, but the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to yii forum post you cannot upload file just by ajax. You need some extra script to do that.

Link to yii forum post: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24525-file-upload-with-ajax/